# trying to graph a decision tree in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Please forgive my naivety.  I am trying to produce a graph of a Decision Tree in Python using Jupyter notebooks. I keep running into trouble, no sooner than I solve a problem, another rears its ugly head. Could anyone suggest a link to an example of code to graph a Decision Tree that actually works?  I have downloaded Python 3.8 (32-bit), Python 3.9 (64-bit), Anaconda3.  An example of a problem is I ran this code:

```
# https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/trees_and_forests/visualize_a_decision_tree/
# Load libraries
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn import tree
# import pydotplus # 
# I pasted this into Anaconda prompt conda install pydotplus
# the error persisted after I said pip install pydotplus
import pydotplus
# Load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
# Train Decision Tree
# Create decision tree classifer object
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)

# Train model
model = clf.fit(X, y)
# continuing https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/trees_and_forests/visualize_a_decision_tree/
# Visualize Decision Tree
# Create DOT data
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, 
                            feature_names=iris.feature_names,  
                            class_names=iris.target_names)

# Draw graph
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  

# Show graph
Image(graph.create_png())
```

At this point I run into a slough of despair:
InvocationException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
10
11 # Show graph
---> 12 Image(graph.create_png())

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py in <lambda>(f, prog)
   1795             self.__setattr__(
   1796                 'create_' + frmt,
-> 1797                 lambda f=frmt, prog=self.prog: self.create(format=f, prog=prog)
   1798             )
   1799             f = self.__dict__['create_' + frmt]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py in create(self, prog, format)
   1957             self.progs = find_graphviz()
   1958             if self.progs is None:
-> 1959                 raise InvocationException(
   1960                     'GraphViz\'s executables not found')
   1961 

InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

​
I have found a few websites that said something about changine the PATH but I didn't understand them.  I am not a computer scientist, I trained in medicine but got a brain tumour, so I learned R and did clinical trial research.  Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

In my case it gave an output in local machine as well as in Google Colab.What I suggest is make a cell and write `!pip install pydotplus` in jupyter notebook itself.Link for Google Colab

> https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11d8kFgNc6Wm2Qawi_e7aSvUHc-SIfYAl?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you Vibhav Surve, I tried adding !pip install pydotplus to a new cell in jupyter, alas it had no effect for me, I still had the same error message the first few lines of which are: InvocationException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-1c1830085316> in <module>
     10 
     11 # Show graph
---> 12 Image(graph.create_png())